# Can't uninstall tool dotnet

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2019, dotnet-tool

AFternoon Everyone,

I have been using the Mock Lambda Test Tool for awhile with no issues. However after a recent update to visual studio 2019 16.10.1 the tool no longer works. I am consistently hit with the error:

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[22900] dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1.exe' has exited with code -2147450726 (0x8000809a).
```

I have found out that there is an issue with the testing tool but when I try to uninstall the tool I get this error:

```
Failed to uninstall tool 'amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1': Failed to retrieve tool configuration: Could not find file 'C:\Users\nacholibre\.dotnet\tools\.store\amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1\0.11.3\project.assets.json'.
```

I also can't install the tool as I get this error:

```
Failed to create shell shim for tool 'amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1': Command 'dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1' conflicts with an existing command from another tool.
Tool 'amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1' failed to install.
```

The folders at the dotnet\tools.store\amazon.lambdatesttool....are completely empty. I tried to rename that folder to do a fresh install but no luck, still the same errors.

So...does anyone know how I can manually remove this tool so I can reinstall??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to rename the exe located here before it would reinstall...

"C:\Users\nacholibre.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1.exe"

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.